# Camel IOException: Stream Closed After Error Handling

Tags: apache-camel

I have an exception handler in Camel that looks like the following.

```xml
<camel:onException> <camel:exception>com.example.BadDataException</camel:exception>
   <camel:handled>  
      <camel:constant>true</camel:constant>  
   </camel:handled>
   <camel:process ref="badDataErrorProcessor" />  
   <camel:setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE">  
      <camel:constant>400</camel:constant>  
   </camel:setHeader>  
</camel:onException>
```

The `BadDataErrorProcessor` is a custom bean that has two functions:

1. Log the error.
2. Populate a graceful error response.

```java
@Component( "badDataErrorProcessor" )  
public class BadDataErrorProcessor implements Processor  
{  
  
   private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( BadDataErrorProcessor.class );  
  
   @Override  
   public void process( Exchange exchange )  
   {  
      logger.info( "Entering ErrorProcessor : process()" );  
  
      orderResponse( exchange );  
  
      logger.debug( "Error Processor setting ID for ..." );  
   }  
  
   public OrderFulfillmentResponse orderResponse( Exchange exchange )  
   {  
      OrderFulfillmentResponse orderErrorResponse = new OrderFulfillmentResponse();  
  
      String errorCode = exchange.getIn()  
                                 .getHeader( ERROR_CODE,  
                                             String.class );  
  
      logger.info( "Inside BadDataErrorProcessor with exchangeID {}:",  
                   exchange.getExchangeId() );  
      Throwable throwable = exchange.getProperty( Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT,  
                                                  Throwable.class );  
  
      if( throwable instanceof BadDataException )  
      {  
         BadDataException validationEx = (BadDataException) throwable;  
         logger.debug( "BadDataException, required fields were mising{} :",  
                       validationEx.getMessage() );  
      }  
      OrderGroupResponse orgpRes = new OrderGroupResponse();  
      orderErrorResponse.setStatus( Status.FAILED );  
      orderErrorResponse.setResponseCode( errorCode ); 
      orderErrorResponse.setResponseMessage( throwable.getMessage() );  
      orgpRes.setStatus( Status.FAILED );  
      orgpRes.setResponseCode( errorCode );  
      orgpRes.setResponseMessage( "400 Bad Request" );  
      orderErrorResponse.addOrderGroupResponsesItem( orgpRes );  
  
      exchange.getIn()  
              .setBody( orderErrorResponse );  
      exchange.getIn()  
              .setHeaders( exchange.getIn()  
                                   .getHeaders() );  
  
      return orderErrorResponse;  
   }  
}
```

After the BadDataErrorProcessor finishes executing successfully, Camel does some magic itself and logs the following stacktrace in the `org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet` class:

```
CamelHttpTransportServlet -  Error processing request
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.throwIfClosed(InputBuffer.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:337) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:205) ~[camel-core-2.25.4.jar:2.25.4]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.copyStream(DefaultHttpBinding.java:432) ~[camel-http-common-2.22.3.jar:2.22.3]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteDirectResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:496) ~[camel-http-common-2.22.3.jar:2.22.3]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.doWriteResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:395) ~[camel-http-common-2.22.3.jar:2.22.3]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.writeResponse(DefaultHttpBinding.java:322) ~[camel-http-common-2.22.3.jar:2.22.3]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:223) ~[camel-http-common-2.22.3.jar:2.22.3]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:78) ~[camel-http-common-2.22.3.jar:2.22.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
```

Can somebody help with this and explain what the "Stream" is in this case, why it got closed, and why camel tried to read it after it got closed?

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to help investigate.

UPDATE:

The problem is that as soon as the Stream is created, it's already closed.

Camel has a `DefaultHttpBinding` that is responsible for writing a direct response. It has the graceful response message I expect. It then converts that into an input stream.

[image]

Then it attempts to copy the Stream, and finally close it.

[image]

That's when it has to read the stream, and complains it has already been closed. Which is weird because we just created the stream.

[image]

Camel created the Stream, and is the one complaining it's already been closed. Which means camel is the one closing the Stream. It seems like a bug inside of Camel.

The input itself is a `CoyoteInputStream` that checks if it is closed.

[image]

The class has a field that indicates closed or not.

[image]

The problem is that as soon as the Stream is created, it's already closed.

[image]

Comment: Try to enable stream caching (camel.apache.org/manual/stream-caching.html) so that the submitted http request body (of type stream) can be read **multiple** times

Comment: I enabled stream caching and see the same results. I've added my updates to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug with Camel 2.22.3. I resolved by upgrading to 3.2.0.

As soon as a request is received by Camel, the `HttpHelper` extracts the input stream from the http request.
[image]

Then it checks if stream caching is enabled, and if yes, it copies the CoyoteInputStream into a new CachedInputStream and closes the original CoyoteInputStream.
[image]

But when an exception occurs, the DefaultHttpBinding uses the original CoyoteInputStream (which has already been closed) instead of the new CachedInputStream.
[image]